# Exceptions not being caught by 'try'

Tags: exception, haskell

I'm using [hedis](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.6.3) and trying to handle the case of the server going dead. According to the documentation:

> Connection to the server lost:
>   In case of a lost connection, command functions throw a ConnectionLostException. It can only be caught outside of runRedis.

So I would assume I want to catch the ConnectionLostException. However, whilst I can seem to catch it correctly, it seems to also bubble up to the top, and I'm not sure why. Here's some code (just running in GHCI):

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings
import Database.Redis
import Control.Exception

conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
runRedis conn $ ping
```

Now, if I kill the redis server between making the connection and running the command, I get the result I expect:

> ⟨interactive⟩: ConnectionLost
>   *** Exception: ConnectionLost

So instead I try to do the following (I added `>>= evaluate` in order to attempt to force evaluation of the error, but it made no difference):

```
let tryR = try :: IO a -> IO (Either ConnectionLostException a)
tryR . (>>= evaluate) . runRedis conn $ ping
```

This gives me:

> Left Con: ConnectionLost
>   nectionLost

So I'm getting the `Left` result as expected, but halfway through the exception is also presumably being caught and displayed by GHCI. Is this a problem with things not being evaluated?

Comment: I don't understand. Everything appears to be working correctly to me: you've converted the exception into an easily-inspectable `Either` value. What would you have expected to happen instead?

Comment: It looks to me like the redis package is printing a string about the connection being lost in addition to throwing the exception.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm converting the exception, but still (as far as I can tell) seeing it being handled by GHCI as if it's still being thrown. Unless it's as JohnL says and redis itself is printing the message.

Comment: You could probably check if the exception is still thrown or just printed by checking the end status of the process. I think for that reasons you would have to compile your test instead of running it in GHCI.

Answer (score 2):

Like John hinted, there seems to be somthing that prints this message to `stderr`.

Consider this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Database.Redis
import System.Mem

tryR :: IO a -> IO (Either ConnectionLostException a)
tryR = try


main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
  loop conn
  putStrLn $ "exiting gracefully after counting up some numbers"
  performGC
  forM_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
    print i
    threadDelay 10000 -- 0.05 seconds
  where
    loop conn = do

      e <- tryR . (>>= evaluate) . runRedis conn $ ping

      case e of
        Right x  -> do print x
                       threadDelay 1000000
                       loop conn
        Left err -> do putStrLn $ "tryR caught exception: " ++ show err
```

It prints:

```
Right Pong
Right Pong  <-------------- after this I Ctrl-C the redis server
tryR caught exception: ConnectionLost
exiting gracefully after counting up some numbers
1
test: ConnectionLost
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

This looks like something in the stack is printing this `test: ConnectionLost` (or `test.hs: ConnectionLost` if you use GHCI/runghc) **asynchronously**.

If that's GHC, that is probably a bug, but chances are high it is done by `hedis` or one of its dependencies (I haven't found it in `hedis` itself yet).

Comment: Also, consider opening an issue for [hedis](https://github.com/informatikr/hedis/issues) to clarify if it's hedis or one of its dependencies.